# AWS Cognito iOS Developer Authenticated Identities

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am trying to use amazon cognito with developer authenticated identities. My API is successfully returning an id and token. However, when I use these tokens to upload content to S3 I receive the following error:

```
Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity
```

Below is my code for setting up the credentials provider.

```
ZGAWSIdentityProvider *identityProvider = [ZGAWSIdentityProvider new];
[identityProvider setIdentityPoolId:AWS_IDENTITY_POOL_ID];

AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc]
                                           initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                           identityProvider:identityProvider
                                           unauthRoleArn:AWS_UNAUTH_ROLE_ARN
                                           authRoleArn:AWS_AUTH_ROLE_ARN];


AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [AWSServiceConfiguration configurationWithRegion:AWSRegionUSWest1
                                                                      credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
```

And I am using the template provided at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/cognito-auth.html#create-an-identity-pool-that-supports-developer-authenticated-identities to create the identity provider.

```
@implementation ZGAWSIdentityProvider
@synthesize identityPoolId=_identityPoolId;
@synthesize identityId=_identityId;
@synthesize token=_token;


- (BFTask *)getIdentityId {
    // Should ensure that identityId property is valid. The below code can probably
    // be used for most use cases.

    if (self.identityId) {
        return [BFTask taskWithResult:nil];
    } else {
        return [[BFTask taskWithResult:nil] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
            if (!self.identityId) {
                return [self refresh];
            }
            return nil;
        }];
    }
}

- (BFTask *)refresh {

    BFTaskCompletionSource *task = [BFTaskCompletionSource taskCompletionSource];
    __weak __typeof(self)weakSelf = self;
    [[ZGAccountController sharedInstance] getAWSCredentialsWithCompletion:^(NSDictionary *credentials) {

        if (credentials && [credentials objectForKey:@"identity_id"] && [credentials objectForKey:@"identity_id"]) {
            __strong __typeof(weakSelf)strongSelf = weakSelf;
            strongSelf.identityId = [credentials objectForKey:@"identity_id"];
            strongSelf.token = [credentials objectForKey:@"token"];
            [task setResult:nil];
        } else {
            NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"com.##.##" code:-1 userInfo:nil];
            [task setError:error];
        }

    }];

    return task.task;
}

@end
```

It appears to be an issue with Role Trust. I created the identity pool using the amazon web interface and have double checked that the identity pool id is correct. I have been able to successfully upload w unauthenticated identities, so I believe is not a role permissions issue.

Comment: Maybe a bit off the topic but I want to ask what is the reason to have `return [[BFTask ...];` in `else` block of `-getIdentityID` method instead of simple `return [self refresh];` ?

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for all the trouble.

There is a small issue with how the identity provider and credentials provider interact that is not properly documented or handled well. The credentials provider pivots using the unauth or auth role arn based on whether or not there are logins attached on the provider.  If you aren’t storing any additional logins on the provider, it will treat it as unauthenticated and use the unauth role and result in the STS error you are seeing. You can work around this by doing something like the following in your identity provider’s refresh:

```
// add login to the map to make sure CredentialsProvider treats us as authenticated
NSMutableDictionary *temp = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:self.logins];
[temp setObject:@"temp" forKey:@"myprovider"];
self.logins = temp;
```

**Update 2015-03-10**: You may want to consider looking at our [end-to-end example](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3E3NJURV1LNV1/Integrating-Amazon-Cognito-using-developer-authenticated-identities-An-end-to-en) for a better method for handling this.

This the sample, we include the the actual values for the user identifier, then pass the entire contents of the `logins` property to the backend.

Comment: Thank you! That was precisely the issue... everything works as expected now.

Comment: that saved me as well, any reason this is not in the doc?

Comment: We're working on updates for the docs as well as an illustrative end-to-end sample.

Comment: @BobKinney is there any way you can give more context?  Are you literally setting  the value to `@"temp"`   is the key supposed to be my "Developer Provider Name"   Does assigning this have a setter? Can i just return it on a getter of my `AWSAbstractIdentityProvider` sublass?

Comment: @RyanRomanchuk I updated my answer with additional context and a link to the end-to-end sample. Hope fhis helps.

Comment: @BobKinney I am not able to set the token in the refresh method as it says token is immutable, so how do i use the token which i am getting form the server..?

Comment: @MUDITJUMNANI There have been a number of changes in the SDK since this post was created. I would recommend looking at the [sample app](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/developer-authenticated-identities-2-4/CognitoSync-Sample)

Answer (score 3):

If you're successfully able to do this while unauthenticated, there are a few possibilities here.

First of all, make sure your unauthenticated role arn is different from your authenticated role arn.
Additionally, ensure that, in the trust policy (accessible via the appropriate role from [this link](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-east-1#roles)), the amr points to "authenticated".

If you have any other questions, [this blog post](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2UQN4KWI6GDJL/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication) goes over the process at a high level.

Comment: I have followed the blog post linked above, made sure that the unauthenticated role arn is different from my authenticated role arn still without any success.  However, when I set the unauthRoleArn to be the _same_ as the authRoleArn I am able to successfully post to AWS, but I don't understand why this works / don't feel comfortable deploying this.

Comment: Can you confirm that your trust policy amr points to authenticated?