# AWS "Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"

Tags: ios, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am attempting to upload photos to s3 from iOS using AWSS3TransferManager from the [aws-ios-sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios).

I am using AWS cognito **Developer Authenticated Identities** by making a call to **GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity** on a django backend using boto3 and passing the returned token to iOS. I have implemented an identity provider inheriting from "AWSAbstractIdentityProvider", and I set the self.token and self.identityID fields, then pass the instantiated provider I developed to the "credentialsProvider" parameter.

The credentials provider is instantiated as follows in the identity provider I created :

`AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *provider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc]
                                               initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                               identityProvider:self
                                               unauthRoleArn:CognitoRoleUnauth
                                               authRoleArn:CognitoRoleAuth];`

CognitoRoleAuth is the arn for an IAM role I created with permissions shown further below. Immediately below is the configuration instantiation.

`AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [AWSServiceConfiguration configurationWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];`

I then use the configuration created to instantiate an "AWSS3TransferManager" object with the following code:

`AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [appDelegate getConfig];

```
AWSS3TransferManager *transMan = [[AWSS3TransferManager new] initWithConfiguration:configuration identifier:@"poster"];`
```

I created an identity pool in amazon cognito and created a role as suggested with the following permissions:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [{
    "Action": [
        "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
        "cognito-sync:*"
    ],
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Resource": [
        "*"
    ]
},
{
  "Sid": "Stmt15426553753",
  "Action": [
    "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
    "s3:DeleteObject",
    "s3:GetObject",
    "s3:PutObject"
  ],
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::pics/auth"
}
]}
```

It also has the following trust relationship:

`{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "us-east-1:identityPoolID"
        },
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}`

I get this error message every time I try to call "upload" with the transfer manager:

***"Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"***

I'm not sure what I've done incorrectly, but it may have something to do with the trust relationship. Any suggestions? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are experiencing the same issue as noted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290256/aws-cognito-ios-developer-authenticated-identities/26741208#26741208). You can also try overloading the [isAuthenticated method](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSCore/Authentication/AWSIdentityProvider.h#L51) in your identity provider.