# Amazon Web Services : Error - The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: ios, iphone, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have a developer authenticated identity set for Amazon Cognito us in my iOS app

I have followed the tutorial in the documentation:
[Using Developer Authenticated Identities](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/cognito-auth.html#create-an-identity-pool-that-supports-developer-authenticated-identities)

My backend is able to generate tokens and get identityIds with no problem.
And I am able to initialize cognito in my iOS app as instructed.
But I upon making a dynamoDb request I get the error

```
The security token included in the request is invalid
```

Cognito initialization Code:

```
 MyIdentityProvider *identityProvider = [MyIdentityProvider new];
[identityProvider setIdentityPoolId:COGNITO_POOL_ID];

AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider  = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc]
                                                       initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                       identityProvider:identityProvider
                                                       unauthRoleArn:nil
                                                       authRoleArn:COGNITO_ROLE_AUTH];




AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [AWSServiceConfiguration configurationWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                                      credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;





[[credentialsProvider getIdentityId] continueWithSuccessBlock:^id(BFTask *task){

 //In here I can see that everything is ok.
 //I have a token and cognitoId
 //But despite this, when I make requests I get "The security token included in the request is  invalid"

 return nil;
}];
```

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong ?

Comment: You should enable verbose logging by calling `[AWSLogger defaultLogger].logLevel = AWSLogLevelVerbose;`. It may be a great first step to debug the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getIdentityId` only ensures that you are getting an identityId, you may want to validate that you can successfully call `refresh` on the credentials provider as this will ensure that you are able to successfully get credentials. Explicitly calling `refresh` should not be necessary in production but can be valuable in testing.

One thing that may also be tripping you up is that you are not including an unauth role. Make sure your identity provider is not experiencing the issues noted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290256/aws-cognito-ios-developer-authenticated-identities/26741208#26741208) which would prevent it from picking up your auth role.

Comment: I checked the refresh and created an unauthenticated role to use. I am now getting "Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity" error. I have checked the role Trust and permissions and everything looks in order... any ideas?