# Can't assume authenticated role with Developer Authentication Swift Cognito

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I can successfully retrieve a token and identity from LambdAuth (my developer authentication) but when I try to use a service, Cognito assumes an unauthenticated role.  Here is my error:

`Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSDynamoDBErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/Cognito_LambdAuthUnauth_Role/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:ListTables on resource: *, __type=com.amazon.coral.service#AccessDeniedException}`

I was expecting the role to be CognitoLambdAuthAuth_Role.

Here is my identity provider code:

```
//  MyIdentityProvider.swift

import Foundation
import AWSCore
import AWSCognito
import AWSLambda

class MyIdentityProvider: AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider {
    var _token: String!
    var _logins: [ NSObject : AnyObject ]!

    var email: String!
    var password: String!

    override var token: String {
        get {
            return _token
        }
    }

    override var logins: [ NSObject : AnyObject ]! {
        get {
            return _logins
        }
        set {
            _logins = newValue
        }
    }

    override func getIdentityId() -> AWSTask! {

        if self.identityId != nil {
            return AWSTask(result: self.identityId)
        }else{
            return AWSTask(result: nil).continueWithBlock({ (task) -> AnyObject! in
                if self.identityId == nil {
                    return self.refresh()
                }
                return AWSTask(result: self.identityId)
            })
        }
    }

    override func refresh() -> AWSTask! {

        let invocationRequest = AWSLambdaInvokerInvocationRequest()
        invocationRequest.functionName = "LambdAuthLogin"
        invocationRequest.invocationType = AWSLambdaInvocationType.RequestResponse
        invocationRequest.payload = ["email" : "me@example.com", "password" : "password"]

        //self.activeSearchRequest = invocationRequest

        let lambdaInvoker = AWSLambdaInvoker.defaultLambdaInvoker()
        let task = lambdaInvoker.invoke(invocationRequest).continueWithSuccessBlock() { (task) -> AWSTask! in
            if (task.error != nil) {
                // failed to retrieve token.
                print("Error invoking lambda function: ", task.error)
            } else {
                //print("response: ", task.result)
                if let payload = task.result.payload as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    if(payload["login"] as! Int == 1) {
                        // The following 3 lines are required as referenced here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26741208/535363
                        var tmp = NSMutableDictionary()
                        tmp.setObject(self.email, forKey: "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com")
                        self.logins = tmp as [NSObject : AnyObject]

                        self.identityId = payload["identityId"] as! String
                        self._token = payload["token"] as! String

                    }
                    print("id", payload["identityId"])
                    print("token: ", payload["token"])
                    print("logins map", self.logins)
                }
            }
            return task
        }
        return task            
    }
}
```

Here is where I invoke the DynamoDB call that generates the error:

```
let dynamoDB = AWSDynamoDB.defaultDynamoDB()
let listTableInput = AWSDynamoDBListTablesInput()
print("listing dynamoDB tables..")
let finalTask = dynamoDB.listTables(listTableInput).continueWithBlock{ (task: AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
    if (task.error != nil) {
        // failed to retrieve identityId.
        if let handler = completionHandler {
            print("Store Data Error occurred: \(task.error)")
            handler(false)
        }
        return task
    } else {
        print("Store Data Succeeded...")
        let listTablesOutput = task.result as! AWSDynamoDBListTablesOutput

        for tableName : AnyObject in listTablesOutput.tableNames {
            print("\(tableName)")
        }
        if let handler = completionHandler {
            handler(true)
        }
        return task
    }
}
```

And the code that retrieves the identity prior to the DynamoDB call:

```
    func getAuthCognitoId(email: String, password: String, identityProvider: MyIdentityProvider)->AWSTask! {
        identityProvider.email = email
        identityProvider.password = password
        // TODO: Store to a keychain

        let task = identityProvider.getIdentityId().continueWithSuccessBlock() { (task) -> AWSTask! in

            let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: AWSRegionType.USEast1, identityProvider: identityProvider, unauthRoleArn: Constants.ARNUnauth.value, authRoleArn: Constants.ARNAuth.value)
            let defaultServiceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
            AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = defaultServiceConfiguration
            return task
        }
        return task
    }
```

**Edit 12/8/15:**

I added API Gateway in front of my lambda function, and still cannot get an authorized role.  It succesfully retrieves the token and idenityId, however:

```
override func refresh() -> AWSTask! {

    let task = AWSTaskCompletionSource()
    let request = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
    request.requestSerializer.setValue(email, forHTTPHeaderField: "email")
    request.requestSerializer.setValue(password, forHTTPHeaderField: "password")
    request.GET(Constants.loginUrl.value, parameters: nil, success: { (request: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, response: AnyObject!) -> Void in
        print("request: ", request)
        // The following 3 lines are required as referenced here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26741208/535363
        self.logins = [self.developerProvider: self.email]

        // Get the properties from my server response
        print("response: ", response)
        let identityId = response.objectForKey("identityId")as! String
        let token = response.objectForKey("token")as! String

        // Set the identityId and token for the ExampleAppIdentityProvider
        self.identityId = identityId
        self._token = token

        task.setResult(self.identityId)
        }, failure: { (request: AFHTTPRequestOperation?, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            task.setError(error)
    })
    return task.task
}
```

Comment: It appears I will have to put the Lambda function behind an API gateway, I'll confirm if I get it working: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=676446&#676446

Comment: So you use Lambda to create a sign up or log in into your ios app instead of cognito or you use both?

Comment: @Lamar cognito is used in conjunction with a developer authentication that was built using lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are calling lambda with unauth credentials

```
let lambdaInvoker = AWSLambdaInvoker.defaultLambdaInvoker()
```

Since it stores those credentials in the keychain for subsequent requests and only refreshes them when they expire, you are still using unauth credentials when you call DDB.  Try fronting your lambda auth with api-gateway so you don't need to start out with unauth creds like your comment mentions and let me know if you still have issues.

Comment: I've fronted Lambda with API Gateway and still can't get an authenticated identity.  I'm trying to see if I need to do a credentialsProvider.refresh() per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/developer-authenticated-identities/

Comment: still no luck.  it wont change to authenticated role.  I've got it set up to work in javascript on another platform so the backend code is good, and the Cognito roles are set up.

Comment: I tried to repro this, but everything worked fine.  2 things to check, is Constants.ARNAuth.value set correctly?  Are you calling any other AWS service prior to calling APIGateway and Dynamo?

Comment: Not explicitly, is there a way to check if AWS has assigned me an identity prior to calling DynamoDB in debug?  like the AWSServiceConfiguration object?

Comment: Whether you have an identity or not is not the concern, it is more what credentials are associated with that identity.  You should be able to get your accessKey/secretKey from the credentials provider object if you have credentials.  Have you confirmed that Constants.ARNAuth.value is not set to your UnAuth role arn?

Comment: it looks like there are values stored for the secret key and access key, is there anything I can check with these?

Comment: Can you turn on verbose logging and see when you are getting credentials and whether it is before or after you have authenticated with your backend?  It should show all the calls to both Cognito and STS and what it is passing as Role ARNS etc.  AWSLogger.defaultLogger().logLevel = .Verbose

Comment: I think I found the problem, but I don't know the solution: `Response header: [{
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 129;
    "Content-Type" = "application/x-amz-json-1.1";
    Date = "Fri, 11 Dec 2015 15:09:23 GMT";
    "x-amzn-ErrorMessage" = "Access to Identity 'us-east-1:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx' is forbidden.";
    "x-amzn-ErrorType" = "NotAuthorizedException:";
    "x-amzn-RequestId" = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx";
}]`

Comment: I also added an action to the policy of that role, and it seems to work now.  Thanks for your help.